# Kubernetes pod stuck with enough resources but without any event

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I have a Kubernetes pod which is made by a replicaSet (and deployment),

As shown in the picture, the pod is stuck:

[image: kubernetes pod stuck]

We have a lot of resources in our cluster (so it doesn't seem to be a resource issue), and there is no event. and I don't suspect anything with `oc describe` command.

**Ready** column in its correct state should be 3/3 (not 0/0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, it was in `spec.template.spec`:

```
schedulerName: default-schedule # ommited r character at the end of scheduler
```

It doesn't raise any clue about this typo, in my case it was even better to leave `schedulerName` automatically set.

Also, reading [this answer](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/11332/41113) might be beneficial.